# node js http createServer socket

Tags: node.js, http, events

The doubt with with code is two things:

1. When i send request through a browser, i dont get a console log message as "connected" but if i use http.get() or http.request() , it works fine
   2)The "connect" event receives a callback with req,clientSocke,head ! now where can i see the server socket ?

   ```
   const http=require("http")

   const server=http.createServer()
   server.on("connect",(req,c_socket,head)=>{

    console.log("connected")

   })
   server.listen(5000,()=>{console.log("server up)})
   ```

Answer (score 3):

1. when you access the server via browser, the method is using GET not CONNECT. That's why console.log does not show.
   if you want `console.log` to show when accessing from the browser, you can use `request` event.

this is an explanation from node.js docs.

> 'connect' event is emitted each time a server responds to a request
> with a CONNECT method. If this event is not being listened for,
> clients receiving a CONNECT method will have their connections closed.
> [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/http.html#http_event_connect)

2. you can make a socket server with a `net` package with `createSever` method.
   this is an example of how to make a simple request to the socket server.

```
const http = require('http');
const net = require('net');
const { URL } = require('url');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('hello world');
});

server.on('connect', (req, clientSocket, head) => {
  console.log('connected');
  // Connect to an origin server
  const { port, hostname } = new URL(`http://${req.url}`);
  const serverSocket = net.connect(port || 80, hostname, () => {
    clientSocket.write(
      'HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n' +
        'Proxy-agent: Node.js-Proxy\r\n' +
        '\r\n'
    );
    serverSocket.write(head);
    serverSocket.pipe(clientSocket);
    clientSocket.pipe(serverSocket);
  });
});

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('server up');
});

// Make a request to a tunneling server
const req = http
  .request({
    port: 5000,
    host: 'localhost',
    method: 'CONNECT',
    path: 'www.google.com:80',
  })
  .end();

req.on('connect', (res, socket, head) => {
  console.log('got connected!');

  // Make a request over an HTTP tunnel
  socket.write(
    'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Host: www.google.com:80\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n'
  );
  socket.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
  });
  socket.on('end', () => {
    console.log('end');
  });
});
```

Comment: but how do we send data from client to server ? when does the http.createServer() callback gets called ?

Comment: and how to see what's in the head argument ? when i console.log(head) it returns as "<Buffer>"